# foo.com is sketchy; “How to Format” and help should use HTTPS links in examples

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, ssl, editing-help

In the “How to Format” bar that shows when editing the body of a question or editing an answer, there is this example for how to format:

```
<http://foo.com>
[foo](http://foo.com)
<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>
```

There is a problem with this: foo.com is a site that is owned by someone currently and has links to a bunch of ads. **It could be sold to a malicious company** and is linked in the Network's guidance. Also, it is a bad example in another way: it's not on HTTPS and thus not secure.

**It should be replaced with https://example.com, which is a site that is set aside exclusively for being used as a random example website in cases like this.**

There is also a related problem: in the help linked to in the formatting bar, [there are examples that use insecure HTTP in the links, not HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links). Sites like https://google.com and https://yahoo.com support secure HTTPS, and the examples should show this; they should set an, *ahem*, example for using HTTPS in links if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "It is done" — Elspeth

[image: It has been changed to https://example.com in the example]

Answer (score 10):

Yes, we need to *set a better example* (I'm here all week).

This includes stuff found in:

- Individual per-site settings
- Transifex for the international sites
- The help center (I believe a few have custom overrides we have to check)
- Baked-in stuff, including posts

The guidance needs to be changed specifically to point to example.com, with guidance on using HTTPS.

I don't have a timeframe, but it's now on the backlog board of curation things that we've been doing a pretty good job of chipping away at monthly.

Will update when done. I coulda *sworn* we addressed this on a large scale previously some years back, but we never quite got out of discussing logistics about it. Anyway, we'll get it done.

Comment: By "Baked-in stuff, including posts", do you mean the How to Format bar?

Comment: Yes, that's what Tim meant :)